# Find and display greatest common divisor from 2 input numbers in nasm

Tags: x86, nasm, dos

Good day,

I have been trying to write a program that does the following:

1. Accept two ASCII numbers from a user (I haven't bothered trying to check the values yet)
2. Convert those ASCII numbers to decimal values.
3. Find the greatest common divisor from those two numbers
4. Display the result

I feel as though I've successfully done steps 1-3, although I'm not entirely sure. Here is the code:

```
bits 16
org 0x100;
jmp main ;

number1_str: db 3,0,0,0,0,'$'
number2_str: db 3,0,0,0,0,'$'
num1_hex: dw 2
num2_hex: dw 2

prompt1: db 'Please enter first number (from 1 to 50): ','$'
prompt2: db 'Please enter second number (from 1 to 50): ','$'

cr_lf:
     db 13,10,'$'   ; carriage return and line feed

;
;Displays a string in dx
;
disp_str: 
    mov ah,09              ;
    int 0x21               ;
    ret                ;

;
; Converts an ASCII string of digits to a decimal number, and puts the result
; in ax, and passes the address to dx. If an error occurs, AL is set to 'E'.
;
str_to_num:
    xor ax,ax              ; initial value of AX = 0
    xor bh,bh              ;                  BH = 0
    mov cx,10              ; To build integer in AX (multiply by 10)
    mov si,dx              ; DX points to start of input buffer
    call next_char         ;  
    ret                ;
next_char:
    mov bl,[si]            ; move contents of memory pointed to by SI to BL
    cmp bl,0x0D    ; Is it a carriage return?
    je finis               ; Yes, we are done
    cmp bl,0x39            ; ASCII for the character '9' is 39h
    jg  error              ; > '9', invalid character
    sub bl,0x30            ; Convert to numeric value (ASCII '0' - 30h)
    jl error               ; < 0, invalid character
    imul cx        ; DX:AX = AX * 10 (32-bit result)
    add ax,bx              ; add next digit
    inc si                 ; pointer to next char
    jmp next_char      ; repeat for next character
    ret                ;
error: 
    mov al,'E'             ; Flag an error
finis:
    ret                ; return to calling program

;
;Calculates the greatest common divisor from the values in
;ax and bx. The GCD will be stored in ax.
;
GCD:
    idiv bx         ; remainder (7) in DX, quotient (1) in ax
    mov ax,bx               ; move bx into ax
    mov bx,dx               ; move dx into bx
    cmp bx, 0x0     ; Is y = 0?
    jg yIsZero              ; Y is zero, return to call from main
    call GCD                ; loop again if y isn't zero
;
; Displays result in ax and terminates program
;
yIsZero:
    xor dx,dx              ; set dx to 0
    add ax,0x30    ; convert remainder to ascii, store in ax
    mov dx,ax              ;
    int 0x21               ;
    int 0x20               ; terminate program


main:
    mov dx,prompt1     ; move prompt1 to dx
    call disp_str              ; display prompt1

    ;get number1_str
    xor dx,dx              ; set dx to 0
    mov ah,0x0a    ; accept string from user
    mov dx,number1_str; address for string
    int 0x21               ;    

    call str_to_num    ;
    mov [num1_hex],ax ; put value of ax into contents of memory address at
                        ; num1_hex

    mov ah,09              ; display string
    mov dx,cr_lf       ; display carriage return and line feed
    int 0x21               ;

    mov dx,prompt2     ; move prompt2 to dx
    call disp_str      ; display prompt2

    ;get number2
    xor dx,dx              ; set dx to 0
    mov ah,0x0a    ; accept string from user
    mov dx,number2_str; address for string
    int 0x21               ;

    call str_to_num    ;
    mov [num2_hex],ax ; put value of ax into contents of memory address at
                        ; num2_hex

    mov ah,09              ; display string
    mov dx,cr_lf       ; display carriage return and line feed
    int 0x21               ;

    ; Find the greatest common divisor
    xor dx,dx              ; set dx to 0
    mov ax,num1_hex   ; move value in num1_hex to ax
    mov bx,num2_hex   ; move value in num2_hex to bx
    call GCD               ; find greatest common divisor from values in ax and bx
```

I'm expecting y_is_zero to display a result, but all it does is wait for entry when I run the code above. If I press any key, the program just ends. I

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
- JS

Comment: What platform is this written for/run on?

Comment: It's written for and run on a Windows XP SP3 32 bit system.

Comment: _"I feel as though I've successfully done steps 1-3 ... all it does is wait for entry when I run the code above. If I press any key, the program just ends"_. That does not sound like steps 1-3 have been done successfully to me. Step 1 involved reading some numbers, but you say that the program exits as soon as you press a key. Can you clarify exactly what happens?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining well enough. I meant that I think steps 1-3 have been completed successfully, then after I have entered input, I press a key and it just exits. When I run it, it asks me for the input for both numbers, and it takes both of them. After I press enter when I enter the second number, it waits for another key to be entered. When I press any key, it terminates without displaying anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GDC` does not appear to attempt to display anything; it never calls `disp_str`, and the system call it makes (before the one to exit the program) does not match the one in that subroutine.

Comment: Oh. I need to change 'jg yiszero' to 'je yiszero' so that yiszero is called, and thus displays something.